# MySQL query returning empty set

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a query, simplified as:

```
SELECT 
    `table1`.`col`, 
    `table2`.`col`, 
    `table3`.`col`, 
FROM 
    `table1`, 
    `table2`, 
    `table3` 
WHERE 
    `table1`.`col` = `table2`.`col` AND 
    `table2`.`col` = `table3`.`col` AND 
    `table3`.`col` = 'x'
```

It does the trick most of the time, except for in cases where `table2.col` doesn't have anything that matches `table3.col`

How can I adjust my query to still show the data from the other two tables, even when `table2` doesn't have any matching data.

PS, this is obviously an example, I realize that if this were a real query I would be returning the same exact value from all the 3 tables. Thank you kindly.

Comment: Use of Outer (left, right, or full outer) joins. http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ for a better understanding.  Inner join such as what you're using must have records in each table.  Outer joins will return all records from all tables, all records from just one table and matching records from others, or various combinations.  Outer joins is what you're after though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is, you can't, you're doing a changed `a->b->c` join. if there's no matching records in `b`, then there can't possibly be any matching records in `c` either.

No idea what your table structure/relationships are, but if you rewrite the join as

```
a->b
a->c
```

then you could get `c` records, even if there's nothing in `b`:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.col = c.col // note: joining a->b
LEFT JOIN c ON a.col = c.col // note: joining a->c
```

Comment: Beautifully explained, that really helped me wrap my head around around it.